# Programatically specify the datasource name for JPA (Specifically hibernate), to use for its database connection within Wildfly, for each request

Tags: hibernate, datasource, wildfly, multi-tenant

I have a multitennanted application running in Jboss 5.  Currently this is not making use of hibernate, but I'm attempting to upgrade it to do so.  All is fine except the application determines which datasource to use based on a subdomain in the URL that is requested.  e.g. a request to `company1.myapp.com/resource/id/1` will request a connection from JNDI for DSN `java:/datasources/company1` and a request to `company2.myapp.com/resource/id/1` will request a connection from JNDI for DSN `java:/datasources/company2` each one connecting to its own database to prevent any possible data leakage.

I'd like to do a similar thing with hibernate under Jboss 8 (Wildfly).  Unfortunately because Wildfly is managing my `HibernatePersistenceProvider` (I just inject my EntityManager, and let Wildfly do all the work) I can't tell it programatically which DSN to use for its connections.

Is there a sensible way to do this that I've missed?  I've tried to change the provider to be a custom class which extents `HibernatePersistenceProvider`, except I just end up with an error that it can't find my class.  And I'm not even convinced this will work anyway as I can't get hold of the request in this class very easily...

Basically I need to determine the DSN from the URL and use it to tell Hibernate which datasource to use for each request.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you say about keeping multiple datasource configuration files and that many SessionFactory object?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I'm not using the SessionFactory as I'm using EntityManagers... Did you have a suggestion in mind making use of the SessionFactories?

Comment: Sorry Amogh - but your solutions won't help as the code uses EntityManagers, injected by JBoss, so I can't make use SessionFactories anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Yes my idea is to achieve this you will need to maintain hibernate configuration files according to your subdomain. Like,

> for `company1.myapp.com` suppose we have hibernate config file as
>   `company1_Hibenate.cfg.xml`

and

> for `company2.myapp.com` suppose we have hibernate config file as
>   `company2_Hibenate.cfg.xml`

After this at the of context loading you will build sessionFactories

For example :

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory1 = new  Configuration().configure("company1_Hibenate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

SessionFactory sessionFactory2 = new Configuration().configure("company2_Hibenate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

And now in interceptor you will check domain and accordingly use sessionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

you could specify different persistence units in your persistence.xml, one for each subdomain. Then you could use a cdi provider method to inject the appropriate EntityManager depending on the domain that has been queried.
But if the number of subdomains isn't fixed in your setup this solution won't work.

Comment: Unfortunately - the system has dynamic signups, so I need to deploy datasources on the fly and then get Hibernate/JPA to make use of them also dynamically...